# Parallel vs Simple Assignment question

Tags: python, coding-standards, programming-logic

I'm quite new to Python and learning it on Lynda.com, which does not seem to have any way to ask questions about lesson content. In a video about while loops there is this code:

```
a, b = 0, 1
while b < 50:
    print(b)
    a, b = b, a + b
```

that results in: `1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34` . Out of curiosity, I changed the `a, b = b, a + b` parallel assignment to two separate simple assignments:

```
a = b
b = a + b
```

but that changes the result to: `1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32`

My question is - aside from the format, how are these statements different? Why is the result different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose `a` is 3 and `b` is 5.

Then:

```
a, b = b, a + b
```

will do the same thing as:

```
a, b = 5, 3 + 5
```

or:

```
a, b = 5, 8
```

i.e. it sets `a` to 5 and `b` to 8.

When you have two separate statements:

```
a = b
b = a + b
```

they run in sequence.

First this runs:

```
a = b
```

and now `a` is 5.

Then this runs:

```
b = a + b
```

and now `b` is 5 + 5, or 10. The end result is that a is 5 and b is 10, instead of 8.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = b
b = a + b
```

In the above statements, the fact that you're using the modified valued of 'a,' (which is now 'b') in the next line is probably the issue.

```
a, b = b, a + b
```

Whereas, in the above statement, the modification is done after assigning the values. And the new value of 'a' doesn't reflect in the 'a + b' part. I assume some sort of temporary variables are created with the current values of a and b. But I don't know Python internal workings.

Comment: There is a fun xor swapping trick that prevents the need for temp variables (extra registers) but indeed that is a detail you can and should happily ignore until performance becomes a critical issue.